# how to convert byte array [1.0.0.0] to integer?

Tags: python, arrays, byte, bitwise-operators, bit

how do I convert byte array [1,0,0,0] to integer 1?
and what's the theory behind it?

i.e:

```
byte array[1,0,0,0] becomes integer 1
byte array[2,0,0,0] becomes integer 2
```

question 1:
what's the theory behind it?

question 2:
how to do this conversion in python?

question 3:
what does [128, 25, 254, 3] becomes to?

question 4:
what's the difference between the result of little endian and big endian?

Comment: #1 is asking for the "theory behind" what #2 is asking for, correct?

Comment: This looks like homework. Which means you're supposed to figure out the answers yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Barmar if you don't wanna answer you don't have to leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

**1.** The standard size of an integer is usually 4 bytes so the array represent 4 bytes to store an integer in memory.

**2.**

```
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes([1, 0, 0, 0]), "little")
1
```

**3.**

```
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes([128, 25, 254, 3]), "little")
66984320
```

**4.**

> In computing, endianness is the order or sequence of bytes of a word
> of digital data in computer memory.

You can see in the example below how the bytes order changes depending on the "endianness":

```
>>> (0x01020304).to_bytes(4, byteorder="little")
b'\x04\x03\x02\x01'
>>> (0x01020304).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big")
b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

> If byteorder is 'big',
> the most significant byte is at the beginning of the byte array.  If
> byteorder is 'little', the most significant byte is at the end of the
> byte array.

**References:**

- [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)
- [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: thanks a lot! that's very clear.

Comment: I actually just tried using "a = arr[0] | arr[1]<<8 | arr[2]<<16 | arr[3]<<24" and it also converts [1.0.0.0] to 1 as well. Was just trying to shift each byte position to the left by 8, to do the conversion, not sure it's correct in theory, but the answer it gives me 1